# Dilation of bounded linear operators

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $A$ be a contraction (bounded linear operator of norm $\leq 1$) on $H$. I heard in a recent talk that there is a (apparently famous) [result](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?agg_year_1953=1953&batch_title=Selected%20Matches%20for%3A%20Items%20authored%20by%20Sz%C5%91kefalvi-Nagy%2C%20B%C3%A9la&fmt=doc&pg1=INDI&s1=169835&searchin=&sort=newest&vfpref=html&r=2&mx-pid=58128) due to Sz-Nagy which roughly states that there exists a Hilbert space $\tilde{H}$ containing $H$ as a subspace and a unitary operator $U: \tilde{H} \to \tilde{H}$ such that $T = U|_{H}$. There also seems to be an explicit [formula](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.09329) for the dilation due to Julia-Halmos.

I am trying to get some perspective on this result; in particular, I would be very happy to learn some non-trivial applications or consequences of this result. I apologize for the soft question.

Comment: The classical text is "Harmonic Analysis of Operators on Hilbert Space" by B.Sz.-Nagy and C. Foias.

Comment: Do you have a response to the answers on this page?

Answer (score 3):

See e.g. [Dilation theory: a guided tour](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.05596) by O. M. Shalit.

From the abstract there:

> For example, every contraction can be dilated
> to [...] a unitary operator, and on this simple
> fact a penetrating theory of non-normal operators has been developed.
> In the first part of this survey, I will leisurely review key classical results
> on dilation theory for a single operator or for several commuting
> operators, and sample applications of dilation theory in operator theory
> and in function theory. Then, in the second part, I will give a rapid
> account of a plethora of variants of dilation theory and their applications.
> In particular, I will discuss dilation theory of completely positive
> maps and semigroups, as well as the operator algebraic approach to
> dilation theory.

Answer (score 3):

The famous application is proving von Neumann's inequality $$\|p(A)\| \leq \|p\|_{\mathbb T, \infty}$$
for every complex polynomial. This is achieved by letting
$$ U = \left[\begin{matrix}\ddots&\ddots \\ & I_H & 0 \\ &&(I_H - AA^*)^{1/2} &A \\ && A^* &(I_H - A^*A)^{1/2}& 0 \\ &&&& I_H & 0 \\ &&&&&\ddots&\ddots \end{matrix}\right]$$
which was proved by Schafer. This has the happy property that $P_Hp(U)|_H = p(A)$ and so
$$\|p(A)\| \leq \|p(U)\| = \|p\|_{\sigma(U),\infty} \leq \|p\|_{\mathbb T,\infty} $$
This is all rather old stuff and dilation theory has generated a lot of research over the years. A good place to look is "Completely Bounded Maps and Operator Algebras" by Paulsen or "Dilation Theory: a guided tour" by Shalit.